# How to add elements to xml data in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Getting data in xml format is new to me, and I get some data with the below format. I need to add more items, and thats my main struggle

Data structure:

```
<Certs>
  <Items>
    <Guid>Value1</Guid>
    <Name>Value2</Name>
  </Items>
  <Items>
    <Guid>Value3</Guid>
    <Name>Value4</Name>
</Certs>
```

The test sample does have 2 elements her, and I need  to add more.

My code:

```
$xmldata = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xmldata.Indent = $true
$xmldata = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\lists\certificates.xml)

$rootElement = $xmldata.CreateElement("Certs")
$xmldata.AppendChild($rootElement)
$childElement1 = $xmldata.CreateElement("Items")
$rootElement.AppendChild($childElement1)
$xmldata.AppendChild($childElement1)`
```

But already here, I get the below error. It might be that I am using the CreateElements("Certs"), but I cannot seem to find out how to work with existing data. I am a bit stuck, I am not a programmer, and a bit clueless here. Any help will be appriciated

Error:

Exception calling "AppendChild" with "1" argument(s): "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."
At C:\lists\communication.ps1:9 char:1

- $xmldata.AppendChild($rootElement)
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
  ```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'

$xml = @"
<Certs>
  <Items>
    <Guid>Value1</Guid>
    <Name>Value2</Name>
  </Items>
  <Items>
    <Guid>Value3</Guid>
    <Name>Value4</Name>
  </Items>
</Certs>
"@

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($xml)

$certs = $xDoc.Root

$items = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Items'))
$certs.Add($items)

$guid = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Guid'), 'Value5')
$items.Add($guid)

$name = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Name'), 'Value6')
$items.Add($name)

$xDoc.Save($filename)
```