# Insert nested elements to XML with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have been writing a powershell script to generate XML but one part has been driving me crazy.
I want my XML to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <container>
        <register name="NoteRecycler" type="StrongPoint.SelfCheckout.Cash.ICashDevice, StrongPoint.SelfCheckout.Cash" mapTo="StrongPoint.Devices.MeiBnr.MeiBnrRecycler, StrongPoint.Devices.MeiBnr">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
        <constructor>
          <param name="loggerService" />
        </constructor>
      </register>
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

But what i get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <container>
        <register name="NoteRecycler" type="StrongPoint.SelfCheckout.Cash.ICashDevice, StrongPoint.SelfCheckout.Cash" mapTo="StrongPoint.Devices.MeiBnr.MeiBnrRecycler, StrongPoint.Devices.MeiBnr">
        <lifetime type="singleton" />
        <constructor />
      </register>
    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

The param element is not added to the constructor element and the error shown when running the script is:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Install\TestUpdater\Test.ps1:140 char:5
+     $paramChild = $xml.configuration.unity.container.register.constru ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Install\TestUpdater\Test.ps1:141 char:5
+     $paramChild.SetAttribute('name', 'loggerService')
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The script i've been working with is:

```
$newRegisterNode = $xml.CreateElement("register", $xml.configuration.unity.container.NamespaceURI)
    $cashConfChild = $xml.configuration.unity.container.AppendChild($newRegisterNode)
    $cashConfChild.SetAttribute('name', 'NoteRecycler')
    $cashConfChild.SetAttribute('type', 'StrongPoint.SelfCheckout.Cash.ICashDevice, StrongPoint.SelfCheckout.Cash')
    $cashConfChild.SetAttribute('mapTo', 'StrongPoint.Devices.MeiBnr.MeiBnrRecycler, StrongPoint.Devices.MeiBnr')

    $newLifetimeNode = $xml.CreateElement("lifetime", $xml.configuration.unity.container.NamespaceURI)
    $lifetimeChild = $xml.configuration.unity.container.register.AppendChild($newLifetimeNode)
    $lifetimeChild.SetAttribute('type', 'singleton')

    $newConstructorNode = $xml.CreateElement("constructor", $xml.configuration.unity.container.NamespaceURI)
    $constructorChild = $xml.configuration.unity.container.register.AppendChild($newConstructorNode)

    $newParamNode = $xml.CreateElement("param", $xml.configuration.unity.container.NamespaceURI)
    $paramChild = $xml.configuration.unity.container.register.constructor.AppendChild($newParamNode)
    $paramChild.SetAttribute('name', 'loggerService')
```

Comment: It is better to use **LINQ to XML** API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839900/how-to-add-elements-to-xml-data-in-powershell/77839971#77839971

Comment: Can you add the code that shows how you create the xml document and the ```configuration```, ```unity```, ```container``` nodes? I can't reproduce the error you're getting with the sample you've provided - the best I can do is get a ```InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'AppendChild'.``` error - this is because PowerShell exposes an *empty* node as a string, not an ```XmlElement```...

Comment: One way to fix that is to use the reference you've got to the parent nodes - e.g. use ```$newRegisterNode``` in your code in, e.g. ```$lifetimeChild = $newRegisterNode.AppendChild($newLifetimeNode)``` rather than the long-hand dot-notation ```$xml.configuration.unity.container.register.AppendChild(...)``` (which gives the ```Method invocation``` anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @mclayton i got the issue solved.

I changed the

```
$lifetimeChild = xml.configuration.unity.container.register.AppendChild($newLifetimeNode)
$constructorChild = $xml.configuration.unity.container.register.AppendChild($newConstructorNode)
$paramChild = $xml.configuration.unity.container.register.constructor.AppendChild($newParamNode)
```

lines to

```
$lifetimeChild = $cashConfChild.AppendChild($newLifetimeNode)
$constructorChild = $cashConfChild.AppendChild($newConstructorNode)
$paramChild = $constructorChild.AppendChild($newParamNode)
```

And that's how it started working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).